# Policies for Growth

Tags: grammaticality

Ensure policies to allow for more higher paying jobs.
Wanting to say we want more of the higher paying jobs.

Comment: Sorry, what's your question?

Comment: Kat, welcome to ELU. When you write a question, please **write an actual question,** as though you were talking to people face-to-face. It shouldn't be necessary for anyone to guess what you're looking for—although someone has, and it might even be correct. If you decide this is a (or *the*) helpful answer, please accept it by clicking the tick in the left margin.

Comment: "Allow for" means "to not prevent" something. Also, "ensure" wants a clause complement, not a direct object like "policies". "Ensure that ..."

Comment: Do you mean "*to set up highly skilled jobs orientated policies*" ?

Answer (score 1):

You could say this as

> Institute policies that allow for more higher-paying jobs.

Instead of "allow for", you might say "encourage" to make it more active in causing these jobs.